# Android - BitmapFactory.decodeStream return null on Samsung devices

Tags: android, android-bitmap, bitmapfactory

This line is failing on Samsung A5 and Samsung Young, and working on HTC, Motorola, Sony, etc.

I've tested the same imageStream but I get different results.

```
decodedBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream, null, decodingOptions);
```

The value of decodedBitmap is always null on Samsung, and I can't figure out why.

In the image below you can check what is the current value of decodingOptions. I've tried don't use options but I get the same result.

[image]

This is the code which Im using. As you can see I'm using Universal image loading and debuging I found this issue.

```
/*******************************************************************************
 * Copyright 2011-2014 Sergey Tarasevich
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 *******************************************************************************/
package com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.decode;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.media.ExifInterface;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.assist.ImageScaleType;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.assist.ImageSize;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.download.ImageDownloader.Scheme;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.utils.ImageSizeUtils;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.utils.IoUtils;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.utils.L;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

/**
 * Decodes images to {@link Bitmap}, scales them to needed size
 *
 * @author Sergey Tarasevich (nostra13[at]gmail[dot]com)
 * @see ImageDecodingInfo
 * @since 1.8.3
 */
public class BaseImageDecoder implements ImageDecoder {

    protected static final String LOG_SUBSAMPLE_IMAGE = "Subsample original image (%1$s) to %2$s (scale = %3$d) [%4$s]";
    protected static final String LOG_SCALE_IMAGE = "Scale subsampled image (%1$s) to %2$s (scale = %3$.5f) [%4$s]";
    protected static final String LOG_ROTATE_IMAGE = "Rotate image on %1$d\u00B0 [%2$s]";
    protected static final String LOG_FLIP_IMAGE = "Flip image horizontally [%s]";
    protected static final String ERROR_NO_IMAGE_STREAM = "No stream for image [%s]";
    protected static final String ERROR_CANT_DECODE_IMAGE = "Image can't be decoded [%s]";

    protected final boolean loggingEnabled;

    /**
     * @param loggingEnabled Whether debug logs will be written to LogCat. Usually should match {@link
     *                       com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder#writeDebugLogs()
     *                       ImageLoaderConfiguration.writeDebugLogs()}
     */
    public BaseImageDecoder(boolean loggingEnabled) {
        this.loggingEnabled = loggingEnabled;
    }

    /**
     * Decodes image from URI into {@link Bitmap}. Image is scaled close to incoming {@linkplain ImageSize target size}
     * during decoding (depend on incoming parameters).
     *
     * @param decodingInfo Needed data for decoding image
     * @return Decoded bitmap
     * @throws IOException                   if some I/O exception occurs during image reading
     * @throws UnsupportedOperationException if image URI has unsupported scheme(protocol)
     */
    @Override
    public Bitmap decode(ImageDecodingInfo decodingInfo) throws IOException {
        Bitmap decodedBitmap;
        ImageFileInfo imageInfo;

        InputStream imageStream = getImageStream(decodingInfo);
        if (imageStream == null) {
            L.e(ERROR_NO_IMAGE_STREAM, decodingInfo.getImageKey());
            return null;
        }
        try {
            imageInfo = defineImageSizeAndRotation(imageStream, decodingInfo);
            imageStream = resetStream(imageStream, decodingInfo);
            Options decodingOptions = prepareDecodingOptions(imageInfo.imageSize, decodingInfo);
            //================FAIL HERE============
            decodedBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream, null, decodingOptions);
        } finally {
            IoUtils.closeSilently(imageStream);
        }

        if (decodedBitmap == null) {
            L.e(ERROR_CANT_DECODE_IMAGE, decodingInfo.getImageKey());
        } else {
            decodedBitmap = considerExactScaleAndOrientatiton(decodedBitmap, decodingInfo, imageInfo.exif.rotation,
                    imageInfo.exif.flipHorizontal);
        }
        return decodedBitmap;
    }

    protected InputStream getImageStream(ImageDecodingInfo decodingInfo) throws IOException {
        return decodingInfo.getDownloader().getStream(decodingInfo.getImageUri(), decodingInfo.getExtraForDownloader());
    }

    protected ImageFileInfo defineImageSizeAndRotation(InputStream imageStream, ImageDecodingInfo decodingInfo)
            throws IOException {
        Options options = new Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream, null, options);

        ExifInfo exif;
        String imageUri = decodingInfo.getImageUri();
        if (decodingInfo.shouldConsiderExifParams() && canDefineExifParams(imageUri, options.outMimeType)) {
            exif = defineExifOrientation(imageUri);
        } else {
            exif = new ExifInfo();
        }
        return new ImageFileInfo(new ImageSize(options.outWidth, options.outHeight, exif.rotation), exif);
    }

    private boolean canDefineExifParams(String imageUri, String mimeType) {
        return "image/jpeg".equalsIgnoreCase(mimeType) && (Scheme.ofUri(imageUri) == Scheme.FILE);
    }

    protected ExifInfo defineExifOrientation(String imageUri) {
        int rotation = 0;
        boolean flip = false;
        try {
            ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(Scheme.FILE.crop(imageUri));
            int exifOrientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
            switch (exifOrientation) {
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_FLIP_HORIZONTAL:
                    flip = true;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL:
                    rotation = 0;
                    break;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_TRANSVERSE:
                    flip = true;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                    rotation = 90;
                    break;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_FLIP_VERTICAL:
                    flip = true;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                    rotation = 180;
                    break;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_TRANSPOSE:
                    flip = true;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                    rotation = 270;
                    break;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            L.w("Can't read EXIF tags from file [%s]", imageUri);
        }
        return new ExifInfo(rotation, flip);
    }

    protected Options prepareDecodingOptions(ImageSize imageSize, ImageDecodingInfo decodingInfo) {
        ImageScaleType scaleType = decodingInfo.getImageScaleType();
        int scale;
        if (scaleType == ImageScaleType.NONE) {
            scale = 1;
        } else if (scaleType == ImageScaleType.NONE_SAFE) {
            scale = ImageSizeUtils.computeMinImageSampleSize(imageSize);
        } else {
            ImageSize targetSize = decodingInfo.getTargetSize();
            boolean powerOf2 = scaleType == ImageScaleType.IN_SAMPLE_POWER_OF_2;
            scale = ImageSizeUtils.computeImageSampleSize(imageSize, targetSize, decodingInfo.getViewScaleType(), powerOf2);
        }
        if (scale > 1 && loggingEnabled) {
            L.d(LOG_SUBSAMPLE_IMAGE, imageSize, imageSize.scaleDown(scale), scale, decodingInfo.getImageKey());
        }

        Options decodingOptions = decodingInfo.getDecodingOptions();
        decodingOptions.inSampleSize = scale;
        return decodingOptions;
    }

    protected InputStream resetStream(InputStream imageStream, ImageDecodingInfo decodingInfo) throws IOException {
        if (imageStream.markSupported()) {
            try {
                imageStream.reset();
                return imageStream;
            } catch (IOException ignored) {
            }
        }
        IoUtils.closeSilently(imageStream);
        return getImageStream(decodingInfo);
    }

    protected Bitmap considerExactScaleAndOrientatiton(Bitmap subsampledBitmap, ImageDecodingInfo decodingInfo,
            int rotation, boolean flipHorizontal) {
        Matrix m = new Matrix();
        // Scale to exact size if need
        ImageScaleType scaleType = decodingInfo.getImageScaleType();
        if (scaleType == ImageScaleType.EXACTLY || scaleType == ImageScaleType.EXACTLY_STRETCHED) {
            ImageSize srcSize = new ImageSize(subsampledBitmap.getWidth(), subsampledBitmap.getHeight(), rotation);
            float scale = ImageSizeUtils.computeImageScale(srcSize, decodingInfo.getTargetSize(), decodingInfo
                    .getViewScaleType(), scaleType == ImageScaleType.EXACTLY_STRETCHED);
            if (Float.compare(scale, 1f) != 0) {
                m.setScale(scale, scale);

                if (loggingEnabled) {
                    L.d(LOG_SCALE_IMAGE, srcSize, srcSize.scale(scale), scale, decodingInfo.getImageKey());
                }
            }
        }
        // Flip bitmap if need
        if (flipHorizontal) {
            m.postScale(-1, 1);

            if (loggingEnabled) L.d(LOG_FLIP_IMAGE, decodingInfo.getImageKey());
        }
        // Rotate bitmap if need
        if (rotation != 0) {
            m.postRotate(rotation);

            if (loggingEnabled) L.d(LOG_ROTATE_IMAGE, rotation, decodingInfo.getImageKey());
        }

        Bitmap finalBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(subsampledBitmap, 0, 0, subsampledBitmap.getWidth(), subsampledBitmap
                .getHeight(), m, true);
        if (finalBitmap != subsampledBitmap) {
            subsampledBitmap.recycle();
        }
        return finalBitmap;
    }

    protected static class ExifInfo {

        public final int rotation;
        public final boolean flipHorizontal;

        protected ExifInfo() {
            this.rotation = 0;
            this.flipHorizontal = false;
        }

        protected ExifInfo(int rotation, boolean flipHorizontal) {
            this.rotation = rotation;
            this.flipHorizontal = flipHorizontal;
        }
    }

    protected static class ImageFileInfo {

        public final ImageSize imageSize;
        public final ExifInfo exif;

        protected ImageFileInfo(ImageSize imageSize, ExifInfo exif) {
            this.imageSize = imageSize;
            this.exif = exif;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In which version of android fails? How are you reading the stream? Could you post the code. Thanks

Comment: Samsung A5 Android 6.0.1 and Samsung Young Android 4.4.2. In the other hand we have HTC One with Android 5.1, Sony Xperia Z3 Android 6 where this code works fine.

Comment: @AndroidRuntimeException I have updated the post with code.

Comment: Why so much irrelevant code to demonstarte that decodeStream returns null? Should we dig through that all? Is it relevant? You can do that with less than ten lines of code. Now please adapt your post. Just put very simple example code that goes wrong.

Comment: Also relevant is: what are the characteristics of the image file being decoded?  Not every last permutation of image encoding will be available on every device.  If you know nothing about the input format, expect decoding to possibly fail, and possibly try alternate options.  The only one that really makes a difference is ARGB_8888 et al.  Go ask Sergey Tarasevich if you suspect defects in his code, not our job to debug it!

Answer (score 1):

By spec `decodeStream` might return null if cannot decode. Look at sources, there are several cases when it's true.
Also decoding is made at native code. So it's depends on vendor.

**Edit**

You can try to read from input stream to byte array and decode it instead of stream. In this case it show you where is a problem: at file reading or at decoding.

Also you could read logs for some helpful info like missing permissions and so on.

Comment: This should be in comments, not as an answer!

Comment: According to debug is a BufferedinputStream, read it from a file.